# Web API 2.2 OData Controller supporting class hierarchy

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, odata

I'm trying to create an `ODataController` that supports casting action.

Let's say we have a Shape class and a Circle class that derives from Shape

```cs
namespace NS
{
    public abstract class Shape {    
       int Id; 
       int X;
       int Y; 
     }

     public class Circle : Shape {    
        int Radius;
     }
}
```

And I want to create a controller named `ShapesController`.

```cs
public class ShapesController: ODataController
{
    ShapesContext db = new ShapesContext();

    [EnableQuery]
    public IQueryable<Shape> Get()
    {
        return db.Shapes;
    }
    
    [EnableQuery]
    public SingleResult<Shape> Get([FromODataUri] int key)
    {
        IQueryable<Shapes> result = db.Shapes.Where(p => p.Id == key);
        return SingleResult.Create(result);
    }
}
```

Everything works fine for a request like

```
/odata/Shapes
/odata/Shapes(1)
```

But requests like

```
/odata/Shapes(1)/NS.Circle
```

causes 404 error

Referring to [routing conventions](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-routing-conventions) I have to create action like that

```cs
[EnableQuery]
public SingleResult<Circle> GetCircle([FromODataUri] int key)
{
     IQueryable<Shapes> result = db.Shapes.Where(p => p.Id == key).Cast<Circle >;
     return SingleResult.Create(result);
}
```

But it does not help - 404.

How can I make my controller support casting? Or maybe my approach is completely wrong and I misunderstand the principles?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.  It was not in controller, it was in the way I was making request.
So, everything work fine only if I put / in the end o  reqest, like that

```
/odata/Shapes(1)/NS.Circle/
```

Comment: That's a bug. A trailing slash should not be required.

Answer (score 0):

This sample should work for you:

Supposing I have the following model:

```
public class Product
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Category:Product
{
    public int Price { get; set; }
}
```

I only need to have this two controller actions both in the `ProductsController` class:

```
[EnableQuery]
public IHttpActionResult GetProduct([FromODataUri] int key)
{
    return Ok(Proxy.Products.FirstOrDefault(c => c.ID == key));
}

[EnableQuery]
public IHttpActionResult GetCategory([FromODataUri] int key)
{
    return Ok(Proxy.Products.FirstOrDefault(c => c.ID == key));
}
```

And both

```
Products(2)/ODataV4Service.Models.Category
```

and

```
Products(2)
```

will be supported with the correct context URLs respectively.

Comment: Thank @Yi Ding, that helped me to find the crrect answer.